# Passing array to function

Tags: php, arrays, function

```
function a($function, $array)
{
    global $test

    $test->$function(implode(',' $array));
}
```

For example, I want to be able to pass the various arguments to a second function inside.

So if I passed `a('x', array('a', 'b'))` it'd execute `$test->x('a', 'b');`

The imploding obviously doesn't work due to making it a string, not passing arguments, unsure how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

```
call_user_func_array(array($test, $function), $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function a($function, $array)
{
    global $test

    $test->{$function}($array[0], $array[1]);
}
```

or

```
function a($function, $arg1, $arg, $arg3...)
{
    global $test
    $arg = func_get_args();
    unset($arg[0]); // because it is the $function arg
    $test->{$function}($arg);
}
```

Comment: Your second alternative takes multiple arguments to `a()` and passes them as an array to `$function`. The OP wanted to do the reverse of that.